# accessing NSS api from Chrome plugin/extension on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to be able to access client certificates from within Google chrome extension. 
Going with the NPAPI plugin seems to be the best choice, but I can't figure out if there is a way to be able to access NSS api that Chrome uses.

Otherwise, I guess I could try to statically link the NSS lib with my plugin, but then I'd have to keep up with the version changes.

It seems that the db is stored under ~/.pki/nssdb. I that distribution dependant or can I cound on that?

Any ideas/help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API to access that functionality. I believe it would be a good to have that API, many applications could use it.

Unfortunately, statically linking NSS library is the only way. That is how Chromium uses it.

Comment: Filing a feature request at http://new.crbug.com/ would be a good way of letting the Chrome team know that handling certificates would be a good addition, either as an extension API, or as an adoption of some of Mozilla's work on `window.crypto` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript_crypto).

Comment: if I check what shared libs chrome references it also references NSS lib - so it linked statically or dynamically? 
I guess what I am wondering is if in my plugin I should use the system shared lib or static linked one - which approach would lead to least pain with different versions of the lib.